# How do I implement firebase authentication in my HTML and CSS webpage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a website with html, css and javascript but i have a problem with implementing firebase authentication. No tutorial has done justice to it. please who has a tutorial I can watch that is updated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try googling this? Like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+in+a+html+css+project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.